# How to create a string table

Tags: c++, string, string-table

Strangely there's almost no online documentation on this subject.  I have an application with hard coded strings for the UI and various other things scattered through the source.  I'm attempting to round up at least some of them because a number of them need to change depending on what platform the application is compiled for.

I used the second example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8440929/618768) (copied below for reference) but it's somewhat light on the details of how this should actually work.  It appears that everything is reinitialized in `project_strings.cpp` and the code is never actually called.

```
// in your project_strings.h
namespace MyProjectStrings {
const char *password;
...
}

// the project_strings.cpp for the strings
#include "project_strings.h"
namespace MyProjectStrings {
const char *password = "Password:";
...
}

// some random user who needs that string
#include "project_strings.h"
std::string password(MyProjectStrings::password);
```

Can someone explain this or tell me its a terrible idea and I should do something else?

Comment: Isn't this explained in the question/answer from where you copied it? Also I do not really understand how your question is different from the one where you copied this...maybe its a duplicate

Comment: The answer just posts the code.  I'm asking how exactly its supposed to work.  The variables all look like they're re-declared in project_strings.cpp.  Also, it seems that none of the code in project_strings.cpp is ever actually run since every time I call MyProjectStrings::password I get nothing.

Comment: Still what you are asking isn't different from the original question and I think you should have commented on the answer (to ask for clarification) instead of asking a new question. I might be wrong, but to me it smells like a duplicate

Comment: The question asked is Qt specific.  I'm asking about C++ standard practices.

Comment: try with 'c' extern. That is you only declare the variable in one location. Then you can define the variable with 'extern' in each place , where you gonna use it.  (don't forget to declare the variable - may lead to crashes)

Answer (score 0):

The example you link is simply declaring some `const char*`s in a namespace in a header file and then defining them in a .cpp file. The syntax used is incorrect for C++ though - the declarations in the header file should be `extern const char*` rather than `const char*` as `const` values default to internal linkage in C++.

Most C++ compiler/linker toolchains will place all the strings from the one translation unit (`project_strings.cpp`) together in a read only data segment of the resulting executable.

This is a reasonable, simple approach to handling static strings although you probably want something a bit more dynamic / sophisticated if you need to handle localization or other complexities.

Comment: Understood, but why is the value of all the strings (null) when I attempt to access them in files that include "project_strings.h"?

Comment: Actually, the example code in the linked answer is wrong, you need an explicit `extern` in the header file declarations since `const` values are not implicitly `extern`.